# SQL - Select Parent if all children are present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
SourceId        DestinationId
1           2
1           3
1           4
1           5
6           7
6           8
6           9
6           10
11          12
11          13
11          14
11          15
```

I want to select SourceId if I pass all its DestinationId to a SP.

Eg: if i pass (2,3,4,5,7,12) in a table type which are destinationIds to my SP it should return 1 since I passed all its destinationId i.e. (2,3,4,5).
But it should not return  6 and 11 since I have passed only 7 and 12 as destinationId, not all DestinationIds.

Comment: what if you pass (2,3,4,5,7,13)?

Comment: SP should return all those SourceIds for which I have passed all it's Destinationid. So in this case also it should return 1

Comment: How do Destination IDs 7 and 12 relate to SourceID 1? They're Destintions of Source 6, not 1. Your logic is unclear here.

Comment: 7 and 12 have SourceIds 6 and 11 respectively but I have not passed all DestinationIds for 6 and 11. So it should return 1.

Comment: kindly explain this question.

Comment: @AbidAli updated question

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, if you passed `(2,3,4,7,8,9)` you would expect no results, and if you passed `(2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10)` you would expect `1` and `2`? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using? (Update your tags.)

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you need two counts.  First the total count of destinations for each source.  Next the number of matching destinations for each source.  Once you have these, compare one against the other.

In the example below I've used two [common table expressions (CTEs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), but you could use two [subqueries](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [temp tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Some tips to help you avoid future downvotes:

1 This question on Stack Meta has some great tips for posting [good quality SQL questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056).
1 This [page, from the help section,](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) talks about the value of providing sample data and expected output.

#### Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
(
    SourceId    INT,
    DestinationId   INT
);

INSERT INTO @Sample
(
    SourceId,
    DestinationId
)
VALUES
    (1,  2),
    (1,  3),
    (1,  4),
    (1,  5),
    (6,  7),
    (6,  8),
    (6,  9),
    (6,  10),
    (11, 12),
    (11, 13),
    (11, 14),
    (11, 15)
;
```

#### Query

```
WITH 
    Total AS
    (
        -- Return the number of destinations for each source.
        SELECT
            SourceId,
            COUNT(DestinationId) AS DestinationlCount
        FROM
            @Sample
        GROUP BY 
           SourceId 
    ),
    SubTotal AS
    (
        -- Return the number of matching destinations for each source.
        SELECT
            SourceId,
            COUNT(DestinationId) AS DestinationlCount
        FROM
            @Sample
        WHERE
            DestinationId IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12)
        GROUP BY 
           SourceId 
    )
-- Return sources where all destinations where matched.
SELECT
    t.SourceId
FROM
    Total AS t
        INNER JOIN SubTotal AS st       ON  st.SourceId             = t.SourceId
                                        AND st.DestinationlCount    = t.DestinationlCount
;
```

#### Returns

```
SourceId
1
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using below sample code. i am assuming that you have all the input passed to you proc into one table -

```
Create table #Source (SourceId  int , DestinationId int )

insert into #Source 
values        
(1          , 2),
(1          , 3),
(1          , 4),
(1          , 5),
(6          , 7),
(6          , 8),
(6          , 9),
(6          , 10),
(11         , 12),
(11         , 13),
(11         , 14),
(11         , 15)


Create table #Input ( DestinationId int )

insert into #Input 
values  (2),(3),(4),(5),(7),(12)

select t1.SourceId , count(t1.DestinationId) , count(t2.DestinationId) from     #Source t1
left join #Input t2
on t1.DestinationId = t2.DestinationId
group by t1.SourceId 
having  count(t1.DestinationId) =  count(t2.DestinationId)
```